# Convert date list into date ranges

Tags: excel, vba, date, office365

I have a sheet several thousand rows in length, & each row has a date in column C. Some dates are consecutive, some are not. I need to convert the individual dates in column C into date ranges, e.g. the following list...

```
13/01/2021
14/01/2021
15/01/2021
16/01/2021
20/01/2021
...
```

...would turn into:

```
13/01/2021 - 16/01/2021
20/01/2021 - ...
```

The date range can go in any column & doesn't have to replace the data in column C. I can highlight if a date is the beginning or end of a range via an IF statement, but I'd like to automate this due to the number of rows needed analysed and I can't think how to do this in VBA.

Using Excel in Office 365.

Comment: Please edit your question, include your code then explain what is not working with your code in details.

Comment: Err you can achieve this using formulas as well....